# Best Practices for Lookup Tables in EF Code-First

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4.1, poco, code-first

I'm doing my first project with EF and I'm planning to go the code-first model. I'm trying to find a bit of guidance about handling a fairly classic "lookup table" scenario.

I'm dealing with a pretty canonical situation where I'll be persisting address data. So, I have a simple address DTO...

```
public class Address
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual string StreetAddress1 { get; set; }
        public virtual string StreetAddress2 { get; set; }
        public virtual string City { get; set; }
        public virtual string State { get; set; }
        public virtual string ZipCode { get; set; }
    }
```

In the state property, I'd like to store the standard US two-letter state code. For validation purposes, I'd like to have a standard one-to-many foreign key relationship between the resulting Address table and a fairly standard state lookup table. That table would probably contain an ID, the two-letter code, and a third column to contain the full state name.

I would expect to use this state lookup table to populate and state drop-down style boxes, etc and also act as a validation to the State filed in the address entity. Fairly common stuff.  So, I have a couple of simple (I hope) questions.

1. Do I need to create an entity to represent the State entity just to
   have EF create the table, or can I just include the table creation
   process in a DBCreation strategy and seed it there?
2. Would it make sense to create that entity, just to use as "view
   models" for any place where I want to display a "state-picker"
3. I really only want to store the two-letter state code in the address
   entity, but does this make sense or does it make more sense to just
   make it a navigation property to a state entity and then display?

I struggled a bit with articulating my point here, so if I'm not clear, feel free to ask for more detail.

Thanks in advance.
    appropriately in the UI?

Comment: 3- I personnally use an entity for that just because it can avoid the typographic errors of the users. I also ensures consistency if you use that in many entities (now or later on). But if your application is fairly small or you don't need too much validation, I don't see much counter-indication to directly put the two letters directly in your Address entity.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. I would make the state it's own class and a navigation property of the Address.

```
public class Address
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string StreetAddress1 { get; set; }
    public virtual string StreetAddress2 { get; set; }
    public virtual string City { get; set; }
    public virtual USState State { get; set; }
    public virtual string ZipCode { get; set; }
}

public class USState
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

With code first EF will create the table, but you can populate it in the `Seed()` method.

1. You don't necessarily need to use view models, but it makes sense to use a shared view for displaying the states in an edit form. You don't mention MVC, but if you use that, then it's as simple as putting

```
[UIHint("StatePicker")]
public virtual USState State { get; set; }
```

in your POCO or view model - depending on what your view uses. Then in Views/Shared/EditorTemplates, add a partial view StatePicker.cshtml, which would looke something like

```
@inherits System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<USState>
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m, new SelectList((IEnumerable<USState>)ViewBag.USStatesAll,
    "Id",
    "Name",
    Model==null?1:Model.Id),
    "Choose--")
```

in combination with

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.State)
```

in your view.

1. Navigation property. Your db will store the USState id as a foreign key, but your app can use addr.State.Code or addr.State.Text, depending on the need. It's much more flexible.

Comment: What if you are using ViewModels? I have tried the approach above and it doesn't seem to work? How would I map between the Id and the lookup entity on the object?

Comment: @Burt My example above is not complete, but the technique will work for using a viewmodel or directly using the model. With EF code first, the framework does the mapping for you. I good (and more recent) introduction to EF and MVC can be found [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application)

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes you can just create a new DBCreation script extending the original script and create a state table which has no relation with the Entity Framework.
2. If I were you I would create the state entity. If state entity is not created, in the end you need to create it in the code, but populating this entity will be a problem, you will need to use sql (you may store this data in xml which seems a better option than storing in sql).
3. If you decide to store the table in the database and directly use it by creating an entity, making it a navigation property is a better option since you may use it directly while lazy loading or eager loading by including it.