# how best to get drop down lists working in my application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

I am new to EntityFramework code first migrations and am struggling to see how best to get drop down lists working in my application. I am used to working DB first and I would have put a TitleId in my view model along with a list and bind the dropdown that way.

I was trying to follow the suggested answer in the following questin

[Best Practices for Lookup Tables in EF Code-First](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10045046/best-practices-for-lookup-tables-in-ef-code-first)

The problem I am getting is that Title on the view model always comes back to submit model as null.

Can anyone give a bit of guidance please?

*Model*

```
public class CandidateProfile
{
    public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
    public Title Title { get; set; }
    public string FirstName {get;set;}
}
```

*ViewModel*

```
public class PersonalInformationViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [UIHint("TitlePicker")]
    public Title Title {get;set;}
    public string FirstName {get;set;}
}
```

*Controller*

```
public ActionResult RenderHomepage()
{
    var viewModel = new PersonalInformationViewModel();

    ApplicationDbContext context = new ApplicationDbContext();
    ViewBag.Titles = context.Titles.ToList();
    return PartialView("~/Views/Profile/_PersonalInformation.cshtml", viewModel);
}

public ActionResult SubmitPersonalDetails(PersonalInformationViewModel viewModel)
{
    //...
}
```

*View*

```
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Title)
```

*Views/Shared/EditorTemplates*

```
@using Temps.Models
@inherits System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<Title>

@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m, new SelectList((IEnumerable<Title>)ViewBag.Titles,
    "Id",
    "Text",
    Model == null ? 1 : Model.Id),
    "-- please select --",
    new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Answer (score 2):

I have seen a lot of issues in the past caused by the drop down being populated using the view bag.  I would highly recommend passing your List through your model instead.  With that your drop down should look like this

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Title, Model.Titles, "--Please Select--", new { @class = "form-control" }
```

the first labda expression is what ties the selected value of the dropdown to your model

Comment: Thanks Matt, that is what I have found as well, not sure why that best practice article suggested ViewBag

Answer (score 1):

`Title` is a complex object, but `<select>` controls only post back single values (or arrays in the case of multiple selects) so it cant be bound. In your case the value posted back from the `<select>` is the `ID` of the selected `Title`. The `DefaultModelBinder` tries to set the value of `Title` to (say) `1` which fails so `Title` is null.

Change you view model to

```
public class PersonalInformationViewModel
{
  [Required]
  public int? Title {get;set;}
  public string FirstName {get;set;}
  public SelectList TitleList { get; set; }
}
```

Since you already using a view model, its better to include the `SelectList` here rather than using `ViewBag`.  Then in the controller

```
public ActionResult RenderHomepage()
{
  var viewModel = new PersonalInformationViewModel();
  ApplicationDbContext context = new ApplicationDbContext();
  model.TitleList = new SelectList(context.Titles, "ID", "Text")
  return PartialView("~/Views/Profile/_PersonalInformation.cshtml", viewModel);
}
```

and in the view

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Title, Model.TitleList, "--Please Select--", new { @class = "form-control" }
```

Note it seems unnecessary to use an `EditorTemplate` for this, and in any case `Model == null ? 1 : Model.Id),` makes no sense. If the value of `Title` is null, then the dropdown will display `--Please Select--`. If it's set to (say) `1` then `<option>` with `value="1"` will be selected.

On post back, the value of `Title` will now be the `ID` of the selected title.

Comment: This is pretty much my thoughts as well Stephen. I am going with your suggestion one thing that doesn't make sense to me is how I map the choosen Id back to the actual model? One is an int the other is an object? DO I need to do a select just to get that object from the context?

Comment: @Burt, On postback, just get the `Title` from the database again based on the selected ID